# 2 line list XML with check box

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a 2 row list XML that also has a check box on the first line.  This data is not saved and it simply to check off the items one the list as you do the tasks listed.

I have 2 problems with this. When I check the first check box another line further down the list also gets checked. The check box does not have an ID but there must be something that says its part of the 1st line or something?

Also when I change orientation the screen refreshes, which I would like to stop as the check boxes are not saved.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BG" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox android:text="" android:paddingRight="-10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10sp" android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:textColor="@color/ndList" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </CheckBox>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Ltext1" android:textColor="@color/ndList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="2"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip" android:text="ONE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Ltext2" android:textColor="@color/ndList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Ltext1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Ltext1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="TWO" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow the first part of the question, the second part relating to check box state saving is answered below:

The activity gets shut down and restarted on orientation change.

use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to store the selected option and restore that selection in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

i.e.

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
bundle.putBoolean("checked", checkBox.isChecked());
}


onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
if (bundle.containsKey("checked")) {
checkBox.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("checked"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure, that you update all the views that can change their content in your intemrenderer. This must be done in your `ListAdapter`'s `getView` method. 
This includes the checkbox too. So if you don't have an underlying data member that holds the checkbox checked state (a `boolean` in your item's data), the checkboxes will keep clearing their states.